# Refresh Excel table connected to Visio Org Chart (insert rows)

Tags: excel, insert, visio, orgchart, external-data-source

I am having an issue with Visio Professional. I have successfully linked an Excel table as an external data source to the Visio Org Chart, when I alter a row in the Excel table and refresh the Visio Org Chart it successfully updates and displays the alterations in the External Data window as well as in the Visio Org Chart. When I delete a row in the Excel table and refresh the Visio Org Chart it successfully removes the record from the External Data window and Visio Org Chart. When I insert a row in the Excel table and refresh in Visio it succesfully imports the row into the External Data window (below) however the data is not linked (no link icon) and thus is not inserted into the Visio Org Chart.

[image]

If rows are added to an Excel table is there a way to automatically link these new rows to the Visio Org Chart on Refresh?